# Write large files to xls/xls in aspnet application

Tags: c#, export, xls

I've a problem with my aspnet web application.
I have to export some queries from db to xls (or xlsx).
In the past I used EPPlus and everything works well with file with max 10K rows.
Now my application must generate file with 100K rows and it's break with memory error. In any case, increasing from 10K to 100K it becomes too slow.
I read on internet EPPLUS has this problem, so I tried also with OpenXML but in this case no memory error but very slow.
Could some one help me to find best solution?
I read about Microsoft.office.interop, but it seems I can't use it on web...is it true?

In any case this is my requirement
1) open existing xls or xlsx with formulas and style yet defined
2) write large amount of rows (about 100K) with best peformance
What's best solution for this problem?
Thanks, 
Regards

Comment: Here is a link that can perhaps help you out. [Write large amount of data to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527343/write-large-amount-of-data-to-excel-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot!